# Calling C# asp.net web service or web method from email without opening browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing an application where approval request email is sent. There are 2 links/buttons in the email: Approve and Decline.

I want to call a URL / web method of C# without opening web browser.

I read about two ways of doing it:

1. Using jquery and ajax {problem here is that Javascript is disabled by most mail clients}
2. By replying to email and then using EWS (Exchange Web Service) to access mails {This process is very lengthy and will require additional server threads to keep on checking mail.}

Please provide an alternative solution (the best possible way to achieve the requirement). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use JavaScript in emails, it isn't (and should never be) supported by any client.

If you're dead set on not opening the browser, your options are to either:

1. Set the buttons to be prefilled **reply-to** links and be listening for email responses (i.e. your #2). This will still require the user to send an email, even if it is prefilled.
2. Create an extension for the email client to call the web service for you (Only really useful for environments where you have control over the clients used)

Neither of these options are easier than just having a link and opening the browser.

Comment: Reece thanks for your answer. I searched little more on internet and I found ASHX handler. ASHX handler does not require browser. I referred this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992046/is-it-possible-to-call-a-webservice-via-a-link

Comment: @Utkarsh the ASHX handler is just another way of a *web server* to handle a HTTP request. It has nothing really to do with the email. Your link in the email will still be a HTTP request, which is still generaly handled by a browser. From a usability perspective how do you plan on letting the user know that their action is successful?

Comment: @Jon Yes, I realized that there will be always an HTTP request associated with it. Actually there was a strict need for not navigating to other window, so I finally decided to use Exchange Web Service. The approve and decline button will point to mailto link which will create mail respectively containing unique identifiers and keywords. Using a server application I am reading all mails through EWS and continuing the further process. Thank you so much for your point :)

Comment: In which case @Utkarsh I've used this (http://independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/index.html) in the past as a wrapper over EWS